# Generate qr code by using php

Tags: php, qr-code

I used the github php qrcode library. I can generate the qr code with no problem. How ever if the generate it and echo some words then the qr code scrambled.

My code is as follow:

```
<?php 
 include "phpqrcode/qrlib.php";
 $link = "http://mail.gmail.com";
 echo "ABC";
 QRcode::png($link);
?>
```

if I comment the echo "ABC", the qr code is fine. Why this happened?

Comment: Because, most likely, it messes up you headers.

Comment: This is because of the headers. Try using ob_start() and ob_flush(). This might fix your problem..

Comment: @SaurabhSinha output buffers won't work either because you cannot send 2 different mime types and contents in 1 http response.

Comment: @SaurabhSinha headers are not the primary problem, there's just 'crap in the output'. The preliminary flush may also cause the output not to be of the correct MIME type, but that's a secondary problem.

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes: i agree with you that is not the primary problem.. but that too will cause the issue even if the QrCode::png() is properly used because the page is already having an out before generating the png image.

Answer (score 5):

The `png` function creates the image and streams its file contents to the browser directly. Echoing data in between is like editing the image in Notepad and inserting random data, thus corrupting the image.

Comment: this is what i explained in the comments... :)

Comment: I know the reason now, but can you give me some more hints to solve it ?

Comment: Well, don't output 'crap' in the code? Don't use `echo` in files that output non-HTML content, such as images. As you said, if the line is commented, it works, so don't put the line in there.

Comment: It must contain 'crap', is it possible to embed the echo with css?

Answer (score 1):

The library you're using sends the data as an image, once you send text too you're corrupting the image.